# Spring webclient exchangeToFlux() not making HTTP request

Tags: spring, webclient, reactive, flux

I'm using Spring WebFlux 5.3.6's WebClient to stream a response from a REST endpoint that generates `text/csv` content.

I can use `retrieve()` and `responseSpec.bodyToFlux` to stream the ***body only*** like this:

```
WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = headersSpec.retrieve();
        Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux = responseSpec.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
        DataBufferUtils
                .write(dataBufferFlux, outputStream)
                .blockLast(Duration.of(20, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
```

but **I want to get hold of the content-type header** and validate it as part of the test. The above code provides access to the response body only, and not the headers.

I've tried to instead use `exchangeToFlux()` to get more control, and access to the response headers, but what I'm seeing is that the HTTP request is never made. If I add a breakpoint to `myResponse.setStatus(clientResponse.rawStatusCode());` it is never hit.

A fuller code sample is below. I've struggled to find any examples of exchangeToFlux that use DataBuffer to stream the result back.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000)
            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(5000))
            .doOnConnected(conn ->
                    conn.addHandlerLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                            .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .build();
    WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> headersSpec = webClient
            .get()
            .uri("http://localhost:8080/v1/users")
            .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/csv");


    MyResponse<T> myResponse = new MyResponse<>();
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    headersSpec.exchangeToFlux(clientResponse -> {
        // Never enters here!
        myResponse.setStatus(clientResponse.rawStatusCode());
        myResponse.setContentType(clientResponse.headers().contentType());
        latch.countDown();

        if (clientResponse.statusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux = clientResponse.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
            DataBufferUtils
                    .write(dataBufferFlux, outputStream)
                    .blockLast(Duration.of(20, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));

            return dataBufferFlux;
        }

        return Flux.empty();
    });

    latch.await();
    return myResponse;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem's like you are not subscribing to the Flux returned from `headersSpec.exchangeToFlux`.

```
 headersSpec.exchangeToFlux(clientResponse -> {
        // Never enters here!
        myResponse.setStatus(clientResponse.rawStatusCode());
        myResponse.setContentType(clientResponse.headers().contentType());
        latch.countDown();

        if (clientResponse.statusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux = clientResponse.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
            DataBufferUtils
                    .write(dataBufferFlux, outputStream)
                    .blockLast(Duration.of(20, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));

            return dataBufferFlux;
        }

        return Flux.empty();
    })
    .subscribe(); // <- Subscribe is missing.
```